# Laravel: Only run migration targeting a specific database engine

Tags: laravel, mariadb, mysql-8.0

Our codebase currently sits on a mariadb clustered backend (10.4) and we need to allow it to also be able to utilise DigitalOcean's managed databases (mySQL 8).

Laravel's password_resets migration doesn't contain a PK which is only a problem for DO Managed DB and can be temporarily set to ignore it by prepending the following to the problematic migration:

```
DB::statement("SET SQL_REQUIRE_PRIMARY_KEY = OFF;");
```

Unfortunately as mariaDB does not understand this statement, it throws an error as "UNKNOWN system variable".

How can I target the statement at either a specific database engine version or allow the statement to be ignored if it errors on it?

Comment: You could simply wrap that statement in an `if(config('database.connection') == 'mysql'){ ... }` (or `!= 'maria'`, etc., whatever fits your configuration).

Comment: Not ideal but I hadn't thought of solving it with a config/env configuration. So not to have to duplicate the database connections, an extra envvar as `MYSQL8=true`, defaulting to false seemingly would be a simple fix. Thanks!

Comment: Agreed, not ideal, but unfortunately the `DB::statement()` function is not DB-agnostic. Anything you write in there will be executed verbatim, and if it's not compatible with the current DB, it will fail. That's why you should try to use Eloquent where possible, but if you can't (such as with this use case), additional constraints are required. Feel free to add your solution as an answer once you get this working. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by adding the following line to the mysql connection in `config/database.php`

```
'mysql8' => env('DB_MYSQL8', false),
```

Then adding a check to the `create_password_resets_table` as

```
if(config('database.connections.mysql.mysql8')) {
    DB::statement("SET SQL_REQUIRE_PRIMARY_KEY = OFF;");
}
```

and finally, if the database is running on DO Managed Databases, add the following to .env

```
DB_MYSQL8=true
```